# How to reduce frequent scavenge in V8

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

This is my test code

```
function Obj ()
{
}

function genObj ()
{
  return new Obj()
}

globalThis.objPool = new Array( 1_000_000 )

function test ()
{
  globalThis.objPool.length = 0

  for ( var i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++ )
  {
    globalThis.objPool.push( genObj() )
  }
}

test()
```

This is d8 trace gc result

```
d8 --trace-gc  test.js   

[35164:000001B1DE2EBBA0]      120 ms: Scavenge 5.0 (5.4) -> 1.0 (2.6) MB, 5.74 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure;
[35164:000001B1DE2EBBA0]      134 ms: Scavenge 2.2 (3.3) -> 1.8 (3.7) MB, 12.10 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure;
[35164:000001B1DE2EBBA0]      155 ms: Scavenge 2.6 (4.1) -> 2.6 (6.6) MB, 18.12 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure;
[35164:000001B1DE2EBBA0]      189 ms: Scavenge 5.7 (8.3) -> 5.2 (7.9) MB, 28.67 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure;
[35164:000001B1DE2EBBA0]      231 ms: Scavenge 6.9 (9.3) -> 6.8 (15.1) MB, 36.22 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure;
[35164:000001B1DE2EBBA0]      296 ms: Scavenge 12.6 (17.3) -> 12.9 (17.3) MB, 55.07 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure;
[35164:000001B1DE2EBBA0]      356 ms: Scavenge 12.9 (17.3) -> 12.6 (29.3) MB, 58.69 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure;
[35164:000001B1DE2EBBA0]      426 ms: Mark-Compact 17.7 (32.6) -> 14.1 (31.2) MB, 14.08 / 0.01 ms  (+ 13.4 ms in 30 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.8 ms, walltime since start of marking 61 ms) (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard; GC in old space requested
```

Multiple gc were triggered in the test code, which affected performance.

It seems that the Obj have allocated young generation, so I want to allocate them to old generation. Is there any way to allocate new objects to the old generation, so as to reduce scavenge gc?

Comment: It's not clear what's being asked. Can you try to rephrase your question details to use more precise technical language: what exactly do you mean by "old space" and "new space"? If you're asking about a technique in JavaScript runtime code to influence allocation of memory (vs reuse) during the creation of new objects: there's nothing in the language to control that.

Comment: In your example code, a possible optimization might be to instantiate the objects at the time of the array's creation: `globalThis.objPool = Array.from({ length: 1_000_000 }, genObj)` ...but only testing will confirm that 

Comment: @jsejcksn: it's perfectly clear what's being asked. "new space" and "old space" are precise technical terms for certain parts of V8's managed heap.

Answer (score 1):

(V8 developer here.)

> Is there any way to allocate new objects to the old generation, so as to reduce scanvange gc?

No. Objects are allocated in the young generation. *Sometimes* V8 will automatically decide that certain allocations should be "pretenured" (i.e. allocated in the old generation directly) because the objects are estimated to be long-lived based on past behavior of the application, but you can't control that manually. That doesn't seem to be happening for this microbenchmark, but since it's a microbenchmark, it also *shouldn't* be the scenario that the heuristics are targeting.

In summary: don't worry about it.

Comment: Can you provide a link to first-party information that supports your answer? I’d like to read more about it: is there maybe a link to a V8 dev blog post or source code, etc?

Comment: @jsejcksn Looks like the introduction of pretenuring predated the launch of v8.dev/blog, but you can find a paper about it here: https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/43823.pdf